# How to encode a string 10 times then decode it ten times python

Tags: python, base64, decode, encode

I'm trying to encode a string 10 times. It starts with a base string let's say "yes" and encode that with base64 then it will encode that encode again on repeat for 10 loops.

Then I'm wanting a function that will decode that which I'm guessing is just decoding 10 times which I'm having a problem with.

```py
def de(string):
    t = string
    for v in range(0, 10):
        f = t.encode("ascii")
        g = base64.b64encode(f)
        t = g.decode('utf-8')
    return t

def decode(string):
    for v in range(0, 10):
        g = base64.b64decode(string)
        string = g.decode('utf-8')
        print(string)
```

```
return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
```

> binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

It only works 1 loop until I get the error

Comment: You're mixing between string encodings for the base64 string. Stick to utf8 only

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, make it _complete_…

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What about removing `binascii.a2b_base64(s)`?
This returns 'yes' for me:

```
import base64
def de(string):
    t = string
    for v in range(10):
        f = t.encode("ascii")
        g = base64.b64encode(f)
        t = g.decode('utf-8')
    return t

def decode(string):
    for v in range(10):
        g = base64.b64decode(string)
        string = g.decode('utf-8')
    return string

s = de("yes")
decode(s)
```